# RethinkDB: convert ReQL to an Integer type

Tags: haskell, rethinkdb

Cannot figure out how to convert reql to a type

I insert a document and get the result back which is an object with "errors" key. I simply need to see if it 0 or not?

So a simple function like this:

```
savePerson :: Handler ()
savePerson = do
  let load = fromJust . extract ["data", "attributes"]
  doc <- load <$> jsonBody'
  res <- runDB $ table "articles" # insert doc
  if (res R.! "errors") == 0
  then setStatus status204
  else setStatus status500
```

This obveously does not compile but it gives the example of what I want.
I need to convert reql to Integer for comparison.
How do I convert types from reql to haskell types?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Apologies for not providing some data types.

```
import Web.Spock (runQuery)
import Database.RethinkDB.NoClash


runDB :: (Result a, Expr q) => q -> Handler a
runDB act = runQuery $ \hdl -> run hdl act

runDB' :: Expr q => q -> Handler Datum
runDB' act = runQuery $ \hdl -> run' hdl act
```

**EDIT2**

Thank you `AtnNn` for the answer the first example works. But I still cannot figure out the ReQL conversion. It is my bad I cannot come up with a good example. I'll try another one.
I simpy get some json, construct response json with `Aeson` and send it back removing the `id` attribute

```
fetchPerson :: Text -> Handler ()
fetchPerson oid = do
  res <- runDB' $ table "articles" # get (expr oid)
  json $ object [
    "data" .= [
      "type" .= ("articles"::Text),
      "id" .= oid,
      "attributes" .= (res # without ["id"])
      ]
    ]
```

Now, `(res # without ["id"])` still gives me ReQL, right? And I need to convert it to a type that is `ToJSON` instance or `Aeson Value` type.
How do I do it? How do I generally convert ReQL to a haskell type?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the runDB function from, and what is its type?

Comment: Its return type is the same as 'run' , it just wraps the DB connection and returns ReQL. I am sorry for not giving the type, i will add it as soon as I am home.

Comment: Are you sure `insert` will return an object with "errors" key? according to [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rethinkdb-2.0.0.0/docs/Database-RethinkDB.html#v:insert) it returns `WriteResponse`.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I was confused by GHCI output which complained about the ReQL mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *Result* instance for [*WriteResponse*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rethinkdb-1.16.0.0/docs/Database-RethinkDB.html#t:WriteResponse) following the example in the [docs for *insert*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rethinkdb-1.16.0.0/docs/Database-RethinkDB.html#v:insert)

```
res <- runDB $ table "articles" # insert doc
if writeResponseErrors res == 0
```

The *R.!* operator is meant for constructing queries of type *ReQL*, not for examining results.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused by the GHCI output about the ReQL mismatch.  This particular example with response result works. Thank you. But, to be honest, I was hoping to get a more general answer here. I still would like  to understand ReQL to a Type conversion. I updated the question with another example. Thank you for helping.

Comment: If you have a value of type *ReQL*, use *run* to evaluate it and get an *Aeson.Value* back.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I did. I think I finally got it.